# How to know the time of my window to calculate the STFT with python knowing only the length?

Tags: spectrogram, stft, window, scipy

I am trying to implement a work presented in an IEEE paper where they have mentioned that the STFT was performed on the signal measurements to obtain a spectrogram with no overlap window of 3 min :

I have used the following code :

```
f, t, STFT = sc.signal.stft(phase_meas, fs=1.0, window=????, nperseg=180, noverlap=None, 
                              nfft=2048, detrend=False, return_onesided=False, boundary='zeros', padded=True,
                              axis=-1)
```

My problem is that I am not able to know the window's type because they did not mention that in the work, Only they have indicated that the size is 3 minutes and knowing that my sampling rate is 1Hz so each block must contain 180 samples that's why I had set the nperseg to 180.

Comment: You would have to ask the authors? How else would you know what they used?

Comment: done ! works perfectly